# Select all values $in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to get all values if `$in` param is `undefined` or `empty`:

```
var users = req.body.users;

Bill.find({
        user : {$in: users ? users : /* GET ALL*/}, //<-----
    })...
```

Comment: Something like that: `var filter = users ? { user : { $in: users }} : {}`. And use this filter in `find`: `Bill.find(filter)`;

Comment: @alexmac doesn't work.. :(

Comment: Because it's meant to be `var filter = (users === undefined) ? { user : { $in: users }} : {}` because you need to be a logical value and of course `undefined` is neither `true` or `false`.